# Creating symlink for a file on Windows 7 gives error

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I want to create symlink to a file using the command prompt on Windows 7. The file is located on E partition and i want the link to be on C partition. I tried this command:
`C:\>mklink /d c:\11.txt e:\Test\11.txt` and it said that the symbolic link was created successfully but if i click on the link i get this error massage: `'The directory name is invalid'`

What is the right way to create symlink for a file from different partition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using `mklink /D` you're telling it to create a directory symbolic link and `D:\test\11.txt` is not a directory. So if you try to access the directory `C:\11.txt` it will give you an error.

Just leave out the `/D` and it should work.

Comment: It worked. I didn't know i have to omit /d. I thought using parameters is mandatory.

Comment: If you're unsure run `mklink /?` Parameters that are in `[ ]` are optional. So the only required parameters are `Link` and `Target`.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, I had been using an Administrator-owned Command Prompt for too long until being able to simple use the Explorer context menu to create links.

I believe I used this program to add a nice subgroup to that context menu: [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html)

This is what it looks like integrated into the Windows UI:
[image: File Explorer Right-Click Context Menu opened to show Link Shell Extensions in sub-menu]

Hopeufully that should add some convenience to your process, and remove any potential errors.